# Node.js & Sequelize : res.json on findAll?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an issue with Res.json in the code below :

```
 /* GET all users */
  app.get('/users', function (res) {
    db.users.findAll()
      .then(users => {
        res.json(users);
      });
  });
```

It worked pretty well yersteday but now, it doesn't. I have this error for all res.json only with the app.get which uses findAll...

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.json is not a function
```

I don't understand why res.json is working in all my fonctions but not with findAll :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback prototype / signature is wrong, it should be like that :

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) { ... })
```

In your example, you're trying to call `req.json`, which doesn't exists.

Hope it helps,
Best regards

**EDIT**

If you don't want the `req`, you can't just remove it, because Express expect it to be there, so he will call your anonymous functio with the 3 usual parameters : `req`, `res`, and `next`.
Express cannot guess that you want `res` as first parameter of your function.

But if you want other people to know that you will not use this variable, you could do something like that :

```
app.get('/users', function(_, res) { ... })
```

OR

```
app.get('/users', function(_req, res) { ... })
```

It is an acceptable practice to prefix useless variables with an underscore, if the underscore has no other meaning. Don't do that if you use *underscore.js* or *lodash*

Comment: Oh I see ! I didn't think that it will be important to keep the req even if i'm not using it ! Thanks :)